# How can I split this dataset into train, validation, and test set?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have defined a dataset with my own data, following the instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images, as below:

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))
```

I have looked through the methods of `tf.data.Dataset`, but couldn't figure out how to split this dataset into three parts(train, validation, test) like `tfds.Split`.

How can I split this dataset into three parts?
I hope the size of train/validation/test set to be 80%, 10%, 10% of list_ds each.

Comment: Did do labeled those? and which format is that data?

Comment: The data are jpg/png img data, labeled and split into 7 folders in the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in multiple ways:

1) Put your train, test and validation data into three separate folders and call
`tf.data.Dataset.list_files(...)` 3 times with appropriate file path.

2) Make use of `Dataset.skip()` and `Dataset.take()`. You will have to manually count the actual number of entries to skip/take based on your dataset size.

More information about dataset maneuvers can be found in TF Docs:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data

Hope this helped!